# Validate tableviewer row and display error

Tags: java, jface, tableviewer

I have a editing supported tableviewer with two columns. If the text in my first column doesn't match the regex pattern specified, an error mark should be specified in the row denoting the validation error.

I tried using `CellEditor` but using this error mark could only be displayed in the current row selected. I want all the rows to be marked with an error mark if it fails the validation that I do in the `isValid()` method of `ICellEditorValidator`.

Comment: What sort of label provider are you using for the table?

Comment: i am using column label provider

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `getImage` method of your `ColumnLabelProvider` to return a suitable error image.

Since the label provider only has easy access to the content provider element for the row it would be simplest to have the cell editor set an error flag on the element that the label provider can test.

The cell editor should call the table viewer `update(element, null)` method when it changes the flag value to get the viewer to update the row.

Comment: This validates the whole word when the value is about to be set to the cell i.e., the text is typed in cell and focus moves to the next cell or once the current cell loses its focus. But i need a listener that is dynamic, something like modifyListener() that we have for a simple text widget, which will get triggered for every letter typed.

Comment: Well if you are using a cell editor you can use a modify listener on the text control in the cell editor.

Comment: But in that case, if I set an error symbol to the CellEditor , the symbol vanishes when i my focus changes to the next cell. Every time i click on a cell it displays error message based on the current selection's content and the other error mark in other erroneous cells vanishes. Also, Initially when i enter the text, since the value is not set to the table until i move my focus to the next cell, using getImage() method of LabelProvider sets the error icon only upon moving to the next cell and not dynamically when typing.